# What do I do to use the function repeatedly in different components?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, axios

I've user object in local storage. I stored token and token date here
User object like that;

```
  user: [{
     nickname,
     token,
     tokenDate,
  }}
```

I parse JSON and get data then sending header with Axios. But i don't want to be code repetition. How do i that?

I hear react-component-lib is it right to use this? And last thing i don't know Redux. So don't be found in redux solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case: you can add a header to all the requests with `axios.interceptors`.

And generally: you can always define and export your function, then just import it several times... not sure if that's what you asked for.